# AWS S3 + CloudFront Cost Problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-billing

I need help to understand is it possible to somehow reduce the AWS billing for these.
I'm using S3 only to store audio and video files and then provide them to my users.
To reduce the cost I started to use CloudFront it reduced the cost a little bit, but I'm thinking that some configs are not correct and that's why AWS calculating more much than should be. Main bills is calculated for data transfer.

Please help to understand how to solve that.
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What region is your S3 bucket? Is CloudFront able to cache the files or not?

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to consider. CloudFront will read data from S3 bucket (origin) whenever a new file is referenced or TTL expires for existing files. So make sure you have good enough (long) TTLs for your files.

Pricing also varies for classes of CloudFront. You can also commit monthly consumption and you'll get a discount of upto 30% from AWS on CloudFront usage.

This guide is a good start point to optimise your cost.
https://www.stormit.cloud/post/amazon-cloudfront-pricing-how-to-approach-it-and-save-money

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, could you give me more details, how to do all this stuff.

Thanks.